# Stripe createToken Synchronous

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Currently I have the following validation code:

```
var validatePayment = function() {
        stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
              // Inform the customer that there was an error.
              var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
              errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
              return false;

            } else {
              stripe_token = result.token;
              return true;

            }
          });

        return false
    }
```

And validate payment is called as:

```
if(validatePayment() {
//Do Something
} else {
//Don't do something
}
```

Calling `validatePayment` is always false because its asynchronous function. Is there a way for `stripe.createToken(card)`. Is there a way to make it synchronous?

Comment: How do you call `validatePayment`?

Comment: @FelDev see above

Answer (score 1):

Since `stripe.createToken(card)` creates a promise, you can return that, and then determine the result not in a condition (as currently, which is synchronous) but with a `.then()`/`.catch()`.

```
var validatePayment() {
    return stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) { //<-- note return
};

validatePayment()
    .then(() => { /* payment was OK */ })
    .catch() => { /* uh-oh... */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using promises

```
    var validatePayment = function() {
                    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ 
                      stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
                        if (result.error) {
                          // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                      return false;

                } else {
                  stripe_token = result.token;
                  return true;

                }
              });
    }).then(stats => {
            resolve(stats)
        }).catch( e =>
          reject()
)
```